Can I get git diff --stat to count character rather than lines added/removed?
I'm writing a patch for my code which mainly replaces contents within lines. I want the git diff --stat (and later git log --stat) to show me the numbers of characters, rather than lines, added or removed. I don't need to do this permanently and always, so I don't mind using some different command-line switches or whatever mechanism is necessary for achieving this. Can it be done at all though?
